# Setting Working Directory to Desktop in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

The current directory on cygwin is home/myuser. I navigated to cygwin and found it has a directory called home/myuser and could not figure out how I would navigate to the desktop. I did not want to add a desktop directory there and I could not navigate above the root folder (cygwin). Any idea on how I could do this?

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially covered in the Cygwin FAQ under "[How can I access other drives?](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.accessing-drives)". No, you're not trying to access another drive, but you are trying to access a folder outside of the Cygwin tree. As the FAQ item says, Cygwin maps your Windows drives as `/cygdrive/<drive-letter>`, so your desktop is likely something like `/cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/Desktop`. Note that the path has changed over the years with various versions of Windows and you didn't specify what version you're running, so it may not be exactly that.

Anyway, what I would do, would be to create a symbolic link to that from my Cygwin home folder. Something like this:

```
ln -s "/cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/Desktop" Desktop
```

I put the quotes in because depending on what version of windows you have, this path may include spaces.

You'll probably notice from the FAQ that the Cygwin version of bash accepts DOS-style pathnames, so you can actually do the following:

```
cd "C:/Users/<username>/Desktop"
```

But I recommend avoiding such syntax. Not all Cygwin apps understand DOS-style paths, and you'll only end up confusing yourself if you have to try to figure out whether what you're doing will work with a DOS-style path or not. It's best to just use the Unix-style paths for everything when in the Cygwin environment, unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: Got it, thanks. This is actually the first result on Google for its keywords, so the question should pay off in the future for others looking for answers.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/Desktop"
```

to `.bashrc` file located in `<cygwin install directory>/home/<username>`. This will change working directory to desktop every time you open Cygwin terminal.